# What is a sign that my chain needs to be lubricated again?

Tags: chain, lubricant

I just cleaned my gears, derailleurs, and chain. Lubricated the chain with Teflon dry lube. When will I need to re-lubricate again? Will I hear the chain make sounds? Do I do a visual inspection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you hear your chain squeaking you definitely need to re-lubricate it.  It's also a good idea to re-lubricate after riding in wet weather since the combination of road grit and water tends to strip away the oil/wax.

For more detailed recommendations, see this question:  ["How often should I lube my chain?"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-often-should-i-lube-my-chain)