# Chain guides; yay or nay?

Tags: chain, chainring, drivetrain, upgrades, chain-guide

So, recently i've bought a new chainring online and it will be sent to my home soon. And i thought to myself, should i get a chain guide? The chainring has narrow wide teeth so the chain will not fall off right? Some says the chain will still falls off even on a narrow wide chainring and some says it won't. Is it a good idea to get a chain guide?

Comment: Has your chain been falling off?  In general, it shouldn't be doing that. Is your chain tensioned properly?  See https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5173/how-tight-should-a-fixies-chain-be

Comment: We know nothing about you or your riding. Unless the answer is "everyone needs a chain guide" or "chain guides are completely useless", we can't possibly answer your question.

Comment: I had a bike with 1× setup, used it with both a chainring with narrow-wide teeth and with a chainring with regular teeth (not for geared setup). My derailleur was non-clutched. The regular chainring definitely required a guide all the time. The narrow-wide one didn't guarantee flawless chain retention ether, as I experienced maybe 5 chain drops with it in 2 years. Whether it is acceptable for you or not depends on your riding style and whether one can tolerate a possibility for chain drop. If you compete, you won't want even a slight possibility of a chain drop.

Comment: And yes, I read in many places that a clutched rear derailleur helps with chain retention a lot, so it is not just a chainring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you need a chain guide depends on your bike, what riding you are doing and several other factors, so it’s impossible to answer definitively.

If you still have chain issues either the narrow-wide chainring, add a chain guide.