# What is this complete bicycle chain guard or chain protector in the photo?

Tags: chain, identify-this-bike, protection

What is this complete bicycle chain guard or chain protector in the photo? It has a 3 mpb printed on it. Who makes or sells it?

[image]

 From [How does a chain get filthy and how can you stop it from getting filthy?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44356/how-does-a-chain-get-filthy-and-how-can-you-stop-it-from-getting-filthy)

Comment: Is there a reason you need to know the brand/manufacturer of this particular case?  Can't you just ask your local shop for a chainguard that fits your bike?

Comment: That looks like a stock Batavus or Gazelle bicycle, not an aftermarket part.  MPB is probably "hub gears" in dutch

Comment: @stan what's your goal here?

Answer (score 6):

These chain guards (or "kettingkast" in Dutch) are standard on single speed or internally geared hub bicycles in The Netherlands.
The traditional ones are made from "lakdoek", which is like a canvas cloth covered with a "doping" agent (can be translated to 'varnished cloth' or 'lacquered cloth').  Similar to what early aircraft was made from.

You can buy lakdoek and modern plastic imitation ones from a number of online stores, for example:

- https://www.dutchbikebits.com/lakdoek-chainguard
- https://www.dutchbikebits.com/chainguards/hesling-nostalgia-chaincase
- https://hollandbikeshop.com/en-gb/bicycle-parts-city-bike/chain-guard/

Not traditionally in a "bath of oil" on these bikes, even from long ago.  Although this is the purpose of chain-cases on many other devices, it is not on Dutch bikes.  They are simply to offer a bicycle  that requires less maintenance and can be ridden and/or left outside all year round, rain, hail, snow, or shine.  This is also why internal hub gears, internal hub dynamos, rear coaster brakes and front roller brakes are the norm there as well.

Answer (score 3):

That is a chain case, not just a bolt-on guard.  The bike looks like a single speed or an IGH, so there is no cassette or derailleur and only one chainring at the front.

The case is an integral part of the bike's design, and generally isn't something you could buy separately because it needs tabs and other mounts already in the frame.

Retrofitting one to an existing bike might be possible for a handy-person, but its not the sort of thing you could just buy and fit to any bike.

Originally these cases would have had some oil in the bottom and the chain would be bathed in liquid oil every time around the crank.  That would have helped efficiency and quietness, and the sealed chaincase would have kept dust out effectively.

The pictured one seems to be open at the back, where we can see trackends for tensioning the chain, so it is not an oil-bath design.  The pinstriping suggests its going for a "traditional" look.

Comment: Yeah, you can see the shifter cable coming down to the rear hub, so it's internally geared.